# Neyman-Pearson Lemma for Pareto Distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, pareto-distribution, neyman-pearson-lemma

I have the following problem.

> Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ represent a random sample taken from a population with CDF given by
> $$
> F(x;\beta) = 1 - \frac{\beta}{x}, ~~ x \geq \beta > 0.
> $$
> Based on the this information, develop the M.P. test for $H_0: \beta = \beta_0 ~~vs.~~ H_1: \beta = \beta_1$, where $\beta_1 > \beta_0$.

We recognize the given CDF as the CDF of a Pareto distribution. The difficulty here is that the M.P. test suggested by the Neyman-Pearson Lemma leads to a likelihood-ratio function which is a constant, as I show below.

Upon differentiation we obtain the PDF

$$
f(x_i, \beta) = \frac{\beta}{x_i^2}, x_i \geq \beta > 0
$$

from which the likelihood function is

$$
L(\beta; \mathbf{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\beta}{x_i^2} = \frac{\beta^n}{(x_1 \times x_2 ... \times x_n)^2}.
$$
Thus, the likelihood-ratio function is

$$
\frac{L_1(\mathbf{x})}{L_0(\mathbf{x})} = \frac{\frac{\beta_1^n}{(x_1 \times x_2 ... \times x_n)^2}}{\frac{\beta_0^n}{(x_1 \times x_2 ... \times x_n)^2}} = \Bigl( \frac{\beta_1}{\beta_0} \Bigr)^n.
$$

The fact that the likelihood ratio is a constant causes the problem. Let $A_1$ denote the critical region of the test. You'd have

$$
A_1 = \{\mathbf{x}; \frac{L_1(\mathbf{x})}{L_0(\mathbf{x})} = \Bigl( \frac{\beta_1}{\beta_0} \Bigr)^n \geq c \}
$$

where $c$ is such that

$$
\alpha = P_{H_0} \Biggl[  \frac{L_1(\mathbf{x})}{L_0(\mathbf{x})} = \Bigl( \frac{\beta_1}{\beta_0} \Bigr)^n \geq c \Biggr].
$$

but this probability doesn't make sense.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/344557/119261, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2767098/321264.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is that the likelihood function is only $\beta^n/\prod_i x_i^2$ if all $x_i\geq \beta$, otherwise it's zero.

So, the likelihood ratio is
$\left(\beta_1/\beta_0\right)^n$ if  $\min x_i\geq \beta_1$, $0$ if $\beta_0\leq \min x_i<\beta_1$, and it's not possible to have $\min x_i<\beta_0$.

The LRT statistic can thus be taken to be $\min x_i$.  This is very similar to likelihood ratio testing for the $U[0,\theta]$ distribution, which is a common textbook example.

Comment: I do not understand the claim "The LRT statistic can thus be taken to be $min~ x_i$". Could you please elaborate?

Comment: There are only two values of the likelihood ratio. One occurs when $\min x_i<\beta_1$, the other when $\min x_i\geq\beta_1$. So the test based on $\min x_i$ is the same as the test based on the LR. Sufficiency, or near offer.